# foreach() : invalid arguments passed

Tags: php

I am trying to run the below code and getting an error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ":

```
<?php
function xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {
    if ($start < $limit) {
        if ($step <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be +ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    } else {
        if ($step >= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be -ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Note that both range() and xrange() result in the same
 * output below.
 */

echo 'Single digit odd numbers from range():  ';
foreach (range(1, 9, 2) as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
echo "\n";

echo 'Single digit odd numbers from xrange(): ';
foreach (xrange(1, 9, 2) as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
?>
```

Can anyone suggest what is the root cause as i m unable to find out?

Comment: What php version do you have? `yield` is for php 5.5 and above.

Comment: @Gunaseelan this is just an example from manual. http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Comment: @Cheery:it is 5.4 for me and if that is the case, what can i use instead of yield to run this code with my current php setup?

Comment: The answer below shows how you can create an array inside of the function and return it, do not want to repeat it.

Comment: Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`yield` keyword can only be used since 5.5 version of PHP. Alternatively, you can modify your function to this:

```
function xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {
    $num = array();
    if ($start < $limit) {
        if ($step <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be +ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i += $step) {
            $num[]= $i;
        }
    } else {
        if ($step >= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be -ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i += $step) {
            $num[]= $i;
        }
    }
    return $num;
}
```

and that will work just fine.